# Python Adding values of leaves to nodes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm working with the following dataframe:

```
ID                  Value
01.1                0.0
01.1.1              0.0
01.1.1.01           0.0
01.1.1.01.001       27508.42
01.1.1.01.002       24170.31
01.1.1.02           25861.82
01.1.1.04           0.0
01.1.1.04.001       0.0
01.1.1.04.001.001   28906.54
01.1.1.04.001.002   30396.25
```

The ID is a string. Is there a way to sum the values of the 'leaves' to the 'node' before? I know this is not a tree For example:

```
ID                  Value
01.1.1.04.001       59302.79
```

The schema:

```
1
├── 1.1  
├── 1.2  
│   ├── 1.2.1  
│   └── 1.2.2  
└── 1.3  
    └── 1.3.1  
        ├── 1.3.1.1  
        └── 1.3.1.3
```

Comment: Group by ID and than sum the values in the grouped lists.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it easier.

We can create a new column in your dataframe with the length of 'ID':

```
your_df_name['level']=your_df_name['ID'].str.len()
```

We use groupby now:

```
your_df_name.groupby(by='level').agg({'value': ['sum']})
```

The 'level' will not be descriptive, so you can add a new column with the schema values based on its lenght.

It should be fine.

Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, **vote up** the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It says I need more reputation before voting. The thing is the IDs are all unique, I want to group by 'level'. For example: 

```ID               Value
01.1.1         10
01.1.2         13
01.1.3         11```

And fill the ID that preceeds them with their sum:

```ID               Value
01.1            34```

Comment: Could you explain 'level'? It should be the clue to resolve your doubt

Comment: Like in a cascading tree. In my first example the '01.1.1.01 ' has two leaves ('01.1.1.01.001  and 01.1.1.01.002'), right? I want to add their values to the node.

Comment: ```1
├── 1.1  
├── 1.2  
│   ├── 1.2.1  
│   └── 1.2.2  
└── 1.3  
    └── 1.3.1  
        ├── 1.3.1.1  
        └── 1.3.1.3```